# JPA Query method not returning anything

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I currently have it working with a custom n1ql query, however it's such a simple query, I figured I could just use the built in jpa query method, however I can't figure out the key words, because I'm not getting anything back.

This code works:

```
@Query("SELECT meta().id as _ID, meta().cas as _CAS, * FROM `my-bucket` mb " +
        "WHERE mb.name like $1 OR ANY Parent " +
        "IN mb.Parents SATISFIES Parent.name like $1 END")
List<MyObject> searchObjectByName(String name);
```

This however doesn't work

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface MyObjectRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<MyObject, String> {
    List<MyObject> findBySecondObjectNameContains(String name);
}

@Data
@Document
public class MyObject{

    @Id
    private String objectId;

    @Field
    private SecondObject secondObject;
}


@Data
public class SecondObject {
    @Field
    private String name;
}
```

My test method:

```
@Autowired
private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;

@Test
public void testFind() {
    List<MyObject> myObjects = myObjectRepository.findBySecondObjectNameContains("my name");

    Assert.assertNotNull(myObjects);
}
```

Comment: You are using couchbase not JPA right? JPA is for relational databases

Comment: I guess I assumed it was using jpa in the background. Yeah I'm using couchbase

Comment: I'm not a couchbase developer but you are not using the parameter name in your query

Comment: You mean in the hard coded query? That was just temporarily since I cba to look up the syntax lol, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks correct, a few things that might be missing:

1) In your test, are you sure that "my name" isn't supposed to be "my name%"?
2) Check if you have a primary or secondary index that covers this query (run the same query via web console)
3) When did you insert the data? If you haven't configured couchbase to be strong consistent, you might have been reading an old version of your data